# Time changing randomly on Windows 7 while batch file is running

Tags: windows, batch-file, time

The time keeps changing randomly on my PC.
The operating system is Windows 7 Professional service pack 1
Time Zone: UTC Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
Time changed on March 29th 2020 as expected.
Day Light Savings is checked.

```
    Ran several tests that all started at 01:55 AM on 6th of April 2020.
    Each test ran for 70 minutes outputting time and date every minute monitored via batch file and outputted to log file.

       @echo on
        set loop=0
        :loop
        rem echo Logged time = %time% %date%>> logtime.txt
        timeout 60
        set /a loop=%loop%+1 
        echo Logged time = %time% %date%>> logtime.txt
        if "%loop%"=="70" goto next
        goto loop
        :next
        echo  end time Logged time = %time% %dat

    Results from testing time displayed just before and after time changed

    Test 1 shows time changed by 1 hour 
    Test1: Output should expect time 2:07:42 to change to 2:08:33
    Logged time =  2:03:42.10 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  2:04:42.11 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  2:05:42.12 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  2:06:42.13 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  2:07:42.14 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  **3:08**:33.61 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  3:09:33.12 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  3:10:33.13 Mon 06/04/2020

Test 2 shows time changed by 1 hour  Complete Log
Logged time =  1:55:59.05 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  1:56:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  1:57:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  1:58:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  1:59:59.18 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:00:59.19 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:01:59.10 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:02:59.11 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:03:59.12 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:04:59.13 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:05:59.14 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:06:59.15 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:07:59.16 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:08:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:09:59.18 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:10:59.19 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:11:59.10 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:12:59.11 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:13:59.12 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:14:59.13 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:15:59.14 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:16:59.15 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:17:59.16 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:18:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:19:59.18 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:20:59.19 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:21:59.10 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:22:59.11 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:23:59.12 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:24:59.13 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:25:59.14 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:26:59.15 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:27:59.16 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:28:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:29:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:30:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:31:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:32:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:33:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:34:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:35:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:36:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:37:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:38:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:39:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:40:59.17 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:41:59.18 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:42:59.19 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:43:59.10 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:44:59.11 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:45:59.12 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:46:59.13 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:47:59.14 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:48:59.15 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  3:49:27.61 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  3:50:10.82 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  3:50:11.23 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  3:50:11.74 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  3:50:11.95 Mon 06/04/2020


    Test 3 shows time changed by 1 h
    Logged time =  2:49:50.10 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  2:50:50.10 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  2:51:50.10 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  **3:52:17**.66 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  3:53:17.16 Mon 06/04/2020
    Logged time =  3:54:17.16 Mon 06/04/2020
```

Not sure why the time is changing randomly by 1 hour, as it should have only changed by 1 minute. Need help to figure this out.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: The code you've provided should not skip one hour, so I'm unable to replicate your issue. There's no programming issue which replicates the behaviour you've outlined. Based upon what you've provided in your code and the snippet of your output file, perhaps it would help us if you were to post the entire output file, i.e. all 70 concurrent lines from a single session. As you've used `>>` those lines could be from 2 sessions.

Comment: Is it possible that the `%TIME%` variable is being modified outside of the code you have provided?

Comment: Complete log from Test 2, I stopped the batch running once the time changed. The batch file is only tracking time changes each minute it makes it easier to monitor as the change is random. No variable changes

Comment: Please perform the test again, using only the script I've posted in the answer area. Please do not modify the script, or your environment, in any way. Then provide feedback, including the first two lines output to the console and all `70` lines of `logtime.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is not an answer to your question, I have included it here, for you to test and see if it makes any difference, *(as I could not format it appropriately in the comment area)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo Start time = %TIME% %DATE%
(   For /L %%G In (1,1,70) Do (
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo Logged time = !TIME! !DATE!
        EndLocal
        "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 60 /NoBreak>NUL
    )
)>"logtime.txt"
Echo End time = %TIME% %DATE%
"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T -1
Exit /B
```

---

To try to confirm, whether, as I stated in my earlier comments, your issue is not with the programming, but on something outside of it. I have decided to provide a modified version on my script, *(without changing its structure)*, to omit the looping use of the `%TIME%` variable. If it works as intended, the issue is with your system or that you're overwriting the system variable, `%TIME%`.

Please try this [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
<!-- :
@Echo Off
Echo Start time = %TIME% %DATE%
(   For /L %%G In (1, 1, 70) Do (
        "%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"
        "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 60 /NoBreak > NUL
    )
) > "logtime.txt"
Echo End time = %TIME% %DATE%
"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" -1
Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery( _
  "Select LocalDateTime From Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objItem In colItems
  dtmLocal = objItem.LocalDateTime
  dtMM = Mid(dtmLocal, 5, 2)
  dtDD = Mid(dtmLocal, 7, 2)
  dtYYYY = Left(dtmLocal, 4)
  tmHH = Mid(dtmLocal, 9, 2)
  tmMM = Mid(dtmLocal,11, 2)
  tmSS = Mid(dtmLocal,13, 2)
  tmFF = Right(Round((Mid(dtmLocal,14,5) *100),0),2)
Next
dtS = dtDD & "/" & dtMM & "/" & dtYYYY
tmS = tmHH & ":" & tmMM & ":" & tmSS & "." & tmFF
Wscript.Echo "Logged time = " & tmS  & " " &  dtS
</Script></Job>
```

It uses Windows Scripting Host, to retrieve the none locale dependent date and time string, pointlessly formats it, (to a neater format, not too dissimilar to that which you've provided), and prints it to the file.

I have left the start and end times using the `%TIME%` variable, as it should give you a visual indication of any major difference between it and the the first and last text file outputs.

Comment: Whilst I'm grateful for the feedback, @Chris, I'm a little perplexed as to how you were able to run the script and post back only 41½ minutes after I posted my answer, when the script takes 70 minutes to run. I even posted it just after the hour, given the timezone you provided, so in testing you didn't even see what happened during the hour roll over! If after properly testing it, you no longer have your reported issue, feel free to mark my answer as accepted; thank you.

Comment: script works perfectly displaying start and end time once it has completed. The output is the same but unfortunately the issue is still present. Here is a snippet of the output Logged time =  1:55:29.64 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  1:56:29.15 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  1:57:29.16 Mon 06/04/2020
... had to reduce characters..
Logged time =  2:00:29.19 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:01:29.11 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:02:29.12 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  2:03:29.13 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  3:03:46.66 Mon 06/04/2020
Logged time =  3:04:46.17 Mon 06/04/2020

Comment: @Chris, there seems to be something odd with what your `%TIME%` variable is using for its default format. In the time zone you've identified as yours, with the script I provided your results, I'd have expected your `%TIME%` variable to output `Logged time = 14:03:29.13 Fri 25/04/2020` but yours is apparently using `Logged time = 2:03:29.13 Mon 06/04/2020` and without an `AM`/`PM` designation. It doesn't appear that your system has any idea of what the date or time really is. Anyhow, I've added another batch script you can test, to see if we can narrow down your issue.

Comment: thank you for batch file here is teh output: Start time = 1:56:25.58 Mon 06/04/2020, Logged time = 02:24:25.17 06/04/2020 Logged time = 03:24:53.69 06/04/2020 End time = 4:05:53.10 Mon 06/04/2020 I have installed new Windows 7 pro time changed incorreclty.Ran test from within Bios time never changed, no issue for furture dates and times. Still not sure of the issue here.

Comment: You have an issue which is outside of the scope of my answers, my code has been tested and does not exhibit any issues. Unfortunately the site members here cannot operate as remote hardware and software assistants, so unless you make significant strides to provide more information about your problem PC, we cannot assist you further. For all we know, you have one or more processes/policies, which are modifying the time. Please limit your questions here, only to the code, and use other sites for software and hardware diagnosis.